# how do LED controllers work

Tags: watts, power-consumption

I’m trying to find out if a device only draws the watts it needs to run or if it takes all available

For example

I have led light that’s says max 0,75 watts and the led controller says output 144 watts will the device received 144 watts or will it only take 0,75

So I’m wanting this https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.co.uk%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F113084461265 to work with the rgb one of this https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.co.uk%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F121282462726

Comment: The question isn't "how do watts work", it's "how do LED controllers work".  And -- I dunno.  It's probably a constant-current device, in which case you'll have fried LED for breakfast.  Change the name of your question, and you'll get a better chance at an answer.

Comment: There are many types of controllers. Add the make and model of yours and a link to the datasheet if you can find it.

Comment: So I’m wanting this https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.co.uk%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F113084461265 to work with the rgb one of this https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.co.uk%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F121282462726

Comment: `if a device only draws the watts it needs to run or if it takes all available` .... easily tested ...... plug a hair dryer into an electrical outlet and run it .... it will use something like 1000W  ..... now, unplug the hair dryer and plug in a nightlight with a 5W lightbulb and turn it on .... what have you observed?

Comment: please google `ohm's law` to learn the relationship between voltage, resistance and current  ....... your question is not about power (watts)..... it is about electrical current (amps) ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That LED controller is not a constant current source, just a triple PWM switch.  As long as the controller is rated at a higher max current than the sum of all the attached LEDs the pair will work properly.

Those LED modules have series resistors which limit the current to the LED devices as long as they are operated at the rated voltage.  Use a 12V power supply and you are all set.